# store data which is an output of python program in excel file

Tags: python, excel, csv, web-scraping

`ענת מאירה`

`0546515015`

`2016-07-25`

`בוטוקס ועיבוי שפתיים.`

---

`מחמוד אבו חב`

`0505178463`

`2016-07-25`

`מתעניין בעורך דין לכל מטרה.`

---

`אנעאם אבו חב`

`0542969636`

`2016-07-25`

`מתעניין בעורך דין לכל מטרה.`

---

this is an output got from python scrapping I want to store it into excel/csv file, such as each row contain 4 columns

for example

`+-------------------------------------------------------+`

`|   col 1  |   col 2  |    col 3 |         col 4       |`

`|בוטוקס ועיבוי שפתיים|0546515015|2016-07-25"|ענת מאירה|`

`+------------------------------------------------------+`

how can I achieve it..?
Please Help...
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: 1) write code 2) execute code 3) debug code. You have to do #1-2, we (maybe) help with #3.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

you could just do this on commandline

```
test.py>output.csv
```

This will put all the data in a csv file which can then be read by excel

Answer (score 0):

Start here - https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html. This is standard library for writing `csv` files. For Excel files you can try `openpyxl`, which have to be installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you can use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/).

This is one way to proceed. I assume that each line of output that you have is stored as a variable or something. Maybe something like this and you loop through it:

```
varCol1 = "ענת מאירה"
varCol2 = "2016-07-25"
varCol3 = "0546515015"
varCol4 = "בוטוקס ועיבוי שפתיים"
```

So to get each of those variables written to a spreadsheet you could do something like this:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet['A1'] = varCol1 
sheet['B1'] = varCol2
sheet['C1'] = varCol3
sheet['D1'] = varCol4
wb.save('example_excel.xlsx')
```

This type of thing could be implemented in a loop and you could iterate through the row number to fill the sheet with the data that you want. For more help check out [This Link.](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/)