# Preserve formatting when modifying an Excel (xlsx) file with Python

Tags: python, excel

Is there any Python module out there that can be used to create an Excel XLSX file replicating the format from a template?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood `openpyxl` supports this. This is example from [docs](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#write-a-workbook-from-xltx-as-xlsx):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('sample_book.xltx') 
ws = wb.active 
ws['D2'] = 42 

wb.save('sample_book.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use openpyxl to open a template file and then populate it with data and save it as something else to preserve the original template for use later. Check out this answer: [Working with Excel In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616207/store-data-which-is-an-output-of-python-program-in-excel-file/38616604#38616604)

Comment: No, openpyxl breaks the file